# REST-API HTTP status code for invalid input on a Patch request

Tags: rest, ember.js, http-status-codes, high-availability

There is a Patch request on my application that updates a user's password. We have an Ember validator to block all invalid input except for 1 business rule, which is it should not be a password used as one of your past 5 passwords.

We are currently returning a 400 Bad Request in this case, however my company has a dashboard for component availability and counts 400 and 500 requests as unavailability, because most applications are SOAP and they just expect 200 and 300s. Even though we handle this 400 appropriately through the UI it is still a ding against us. And puts us on the radar as an area with poor availability.

Should we take this to the people that monitor availability and have them change this for REST services as this will become a more common and common occurrence as the company creates more REST applications. Or do we cave and return a 200 that also states that the password was not successfully updated?

Comment: I really think that monitoring is broken. At least most 400 errors are not a sign of bad availability.

Comment: Although REST is just an architectural style and not a protocol, it adheres to the underlying protocol used, HTTP in your scenario. It should therefore also respect and re-use the capabilities of these protocols in use i.e return a propper error code for invalid input. Returning 200 OK for a request with invalid input data may lead to RESTful clients operating on wrong data and therefore lead to even more erroneous input

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that a 400 response is inappropriate for the service.  If the service is responding with a 400 when the user's password has been repeated within the last 5 passwords, then the request ***was understood*** by the server.

According to the [W3C](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed
>   syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without
>   modifications.

In your case, the request was understood.  It is returning a 400 to signal an *application* concern (regarding password reuse).  I believe a 200 response would be more appropriate with a payload indicating the application problem.

**EDIT:**
One might also argue that a [422 response](http://www.restpatterns.org/HTTP_Status_Codes/422_-_Unprocessable_Entity) would be in order:

> The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server
>   understands the content type of the request entity (hence a
>   415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the
>   syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request)
>   status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained
>   instructions. For example, this error condition may occur if an XML
>   request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but
>   semantically erroneous, XML instructions.